# AutoBackup of database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005

how to create auto backup in sql server 2005 programmatically in C# winforms application continuously?
I want procedure, syntax, and proper explanation of my particular question as I am new to C# Winform and also I have not attempted for any of coding

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an SQL Server job?

You could create a [job which could create the backup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/12/create-a-database-backup-job-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx) periodically and then copy it to the target location. You could follow the tutorial link to create the backup job and the next statements to copy the file:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'COPY C:\sourceBackedUpFile \\serverAddress\targetBackupFile'
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a convenient stored procedure **in database** which manages backup.
2. In your C# code, create perioric firing `BackgroundWorker`, `Timer` or similar object.
3. Inside it, adjust opening `SqlConnection` instance and execute `SqlCommand` with mentioned stored procedure passed